# (Processing) TextField condition

Tags: processing, conditional-statements, textfield

I've got some trouble with my Processing code. [Here's my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLcAZ.png)

As you can see, the condition is not working. I've been looking for an issue however I didn't find anything.

Thanks for replying

Comment: Include your code in your question.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] and a specific technical question. Saying "the condition is not working" doesn't really tell us much. What exactly do you expect your code to do? What exactly does it do instead? Have you tried debugging your code at all?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't compare `String` values using the `==` operator. That will only evaluate to `true` if two values are the same reference. It doesn't check the content of the `String` values. Use the `equals()` function instead.

This is covered in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/String.html):

> To compare the contents of two Strings, use the equals() method, as in if (a.equals(b)), instead of if (a == b). A String is an Object, so comparing them with the == operator only compares whether both Strings are stored in the same memory location. Using the equals() method will ensure that the actual contents are compared. (The [troubleshooting](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Troubleshooting#Why_don.27t_these_Strings_equal.3F) reference has a longer explanation.)